# android : WALLPAPER_CHANGED is not working on samsung galaxy

Tags: java, android

i have an application in which i am receiving WALLPAPER_CHANGED broadcast. the problem is that it is working in HTC Desire HD but not working on Motorola Milestone or Droid X. why is that ?? also it is not working on Samsung Galaxy S.

what can be the issue ?

Comment: i have done a workaround for the problem i was working on, but the issue mentioned in this question is still open..

Comment: If you want to post the code, we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with the device and the changed implementation of android in the OS. so we cannot do anything for this problem.